# Add a ICC profile for a printer

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, printing, color-management

I have a Canon printer, using the Linux's stock printer drivers. I noticed that I can select a media type in the printer's properties, under `Printer Options`. This will apparently choose a ICC color profile for the photo paper I want to print on.

If I try to calibrate my printer, can I add my own ICC profile to this list of media types? How can I do that, where do I find the existing color profiles?

Btw: Why do I have to select the media type in the printer's options, but not in the printing dialog?